# Laravel, too many queries, if I manipulate the returned Eloquent collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and some of basic relations between 2 tables

when I try to do anything with the returned Eloquent collection,
I find the DebugBar records a lot of queries

like this example:

```
$articles = \App\Article::get();
return count($articles->toArray());
// DebugBar records about 395 queries
```

On the contrary, If use the collection counting helper

```
$articles = \App\Article::get();
return $articles->count();
// DebugBar records only 2 queries
```

Comment: Please post the `Article` model and some sample queries from the log.

Comment: Thanks @JonasStaudenmeir, my issue solved, I forgot to put every used relation in "with()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections are kind of lazy evaluation when it comes to fetching relationships. When you convert that to an array more queries need to be run to fetch more data. If it's a collection, its a revokable object and can chain methods further to get relationships and will act only according to the successive call.